# How to extend femanager controller under php 7

Tags: typo3, php-7, extends, php-7.1, typo3-extensions

Since using PHP 7.0 and higher, the strict mode of php generates warnings like this:

```
PHP Warning: Declaration of In2code\Femanagerextended\Controller\EditController::updateAction(In2code\Femanagerextended\Domain\Model\User $user) should be compatible with In2code\Femanager\Controller\EditController::updateAction(In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User $user) in ($PATH)\typo3conf\ext\femanagerextended\Classes\Controller\EditController.php line 17
```

when trying to extend an existing controller of the TYPO3 Extension femanager using the described way in the best practice section of the manual:

```
<?php
namespace In2code\Femanagerextended\Controller;
use In2code\Femanager\Controller\EditController as EditControllerFemanager;
use In2code\Femanagerextended\Domain\Model\User;
/**
 * Class EditController
 *
 * @package In2code\Femanagerextended\Controller
 */
class EditController extends EditControllerFemanager
{
    /**
     * action update
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\ServersideValidator
     * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\PasswordValidator
     * @return void
     */
     public function updateAction(User $user)
     {
         parent::updateAction($user);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible solution, worked out by Wolfgang Klinger, is to XClass the \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\Argument class.

This class has a protected property "dataType", which usually has no setter.

Using the XClass mechanism of TYPO3 it is possible to add a setDataType method to enable the manual overriding of this property.

Armed with this, it's now possible to overwrite the usually automatic detected data type inside the (magic) initialize actions of the extending edit/invitation/new-controller.

The important thing is, **not** to change the type hints and annotations of the "normal" Actions (newAction, createAction ...), but add something like this to the corresponding initialize actions:

```
public function initializeNewAction()
{
    if ($this->arguments->hasArgument('user')) {
        // Workaround to avoid php7 warnings of wrong type hint.
        /** @var \Mediagear\Jdcompetition\Xclass\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\Argument $user */
        $user = $this->arguments['user'];
        $user->setDataType(\Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I have to pass some additional data to the view in the newAction() and I get exactly your PHP7 warning. How would I achieve this, because $this->view is not available in the initializeNewAction()? Btw., could you explain your initializeNewAction() example a bit more in depth? E.g. what is `/** @var \Mediagear\Jdcompetition\Xclass\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\Argument $user */` Is this the inharitance of the original User model? Thanks again!

Comment: For how to add new properties to one of the view, ave a look in the manual of femanger. /** @var is only a typehint for my ide to get code completiion for the var $user

Comment: Thanks again! I added the needed variables by using the `initializeView()` method. 
By the way: there is another discussion and a detailed answer about this topic: [Extend TYPO3 femanager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47848908/415353)

Answer (score 5):

Full answer/tutorial ...

You can extend TYPO3 `femanager` with the following [tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/femanager/Features/NewFields/Index.html). The old extension `femanagerextended` is not necessary. This works fine with `TYPO3` and `PHP 5.x`. Here's the workaround for `PHP 7.x`:

Add a new XCLASS-file f.e. `typo3conf/ext/yourext/Classes/Xclass/Extbase/Mvc/Controller/Argument.php`:

```
namespace Yournamespace\Yourext\Xclass\Extbase\Mvc\Controller;
class Argument extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\Argument

{
    /**
     * Set data type for femanager workaround.
     * Workaround to avoid php7 warnings of wrong type hint.
     *
     * @param $dataType
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDataType($dataType) {
        $this->dataType = $dataType;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Change the file `typo3conf/ext/yourext/Classes/Controller/EditController.php`:

```
namespace Yournamespace\Yourext\Controller;
use \Yournamespace\Yourext\Domain\Model\User;
class EditController extends \In2code\Femanager\Controller\EditController {

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function initializeUpdateAction()
    {
        if ($this->arguments->hasArgument('user')) {
            // Workaround to avoid php7 warnings of wrong type hint.
            /** @var \Yournamespace\Yourext\Xclass\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\Argument $user */
            $user = $this->arguments['user'];
            $user->setDataType(\Yournamespace\yourext\Domain\Model\User::class);
        }
    }

    /**
     * action update
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\ServersideValidator
     * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\PasswordValidator
     * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\CaptchaValidator
     * @return void
     */
    public function updateAction(\In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User $user) {
        parent::updateAction($user);
    }
}
```

Change the file `typo3conf/ext/yourext/Classes/Controller/NewController.php`:

```
namespace Yournamespace\Yourext\Controller;
use Yournamespace\Yourext\Domain\Model\User;
class NewController extends \In2code\Femanager\Controller\NewController {

    /**
     * Initialize create action for setting the right custom data type for the user.
     */
    public function initializeCreateAction() {
        if ($this->arguments->hasArgument('user')) {
            // Workaround to avoid php7 warnings of wrong type hint.
            /** @var \Yournamespace\Yourext\Xclass\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\Argument $user */
            $user = $this->arguments['user'];
            $user->setDataType(\Yournamespace\Yourext\Domain\Model\User::class);
        }
    }


    /**
     * action create
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\ServersideValidator
     * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\PasswordValidator
     * @return void
     */
    public function createAction(User $user)
    {
        parent::createAction($user);
    }
}
```

Register your XCLASS into `ext_localconf.php`:
`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Controller\\Argument'] = array('className' => 'Yournamespace\\Yourext\\Xclass\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Controller\\Argument');`

Clear Cache & clear autoloader via install tool!

This [issue](https://github.com/einpraegsam/femanagerextended/issues/1) also helps.

Comment: Hi everybody .. yesterday I've made some extra fields for `femananger`, `TYPO3 8.7` & `PHP7` without all these adjustments (Xclass etc.). I've installed `femanagerextended` and change the dependencies at `ext_emconf.php` and update the Controller-Classes, see example: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/femanager/Features/NewFields/Index.html

Comment: This Link also helps : https://github.com/in2code-de/femanager/issues/185 Caching Problems with femanager and femanagerextended

Comment: This not working for my TYPO3 10.4, femanagaer 6.3.4 and PHP 7.4