# Extend TYPO3 femanager

Tags: typo3, extbase

Does anyone have a working example how to extend femanager 3.3.0 on TYPO3 8.7?

I created a new Extension which does all the stuff (new database fields for fe_user, TCA, Partials,....). I have the new fields in the femanager plugin and can select them for the frontend.

Registering IS WORKING: the new fields are saved in the database.
There is a Warning in the Log:

```
Core: Error handler (FE): 
PHP Warning: Declaration of TOCO3\TocoLedes\Controller\NewController::createAction(TOCO3\TocoLedes\Domain\Model\User $user) 
should be compatible with In2code\Femanager\Controller\NewController::createAction(In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User $user) in \www\typo3conf\ext\toco_ledes\Classes\Controller\NewController.php line 0
```

Nevertheless this seems not be a problem.

BUT: Editing

The Profile Edit Page shows all my new fields (as selected in the Plugin) but does NOT load the values of these fields (they are empty). If I try to save the profile I get the following error:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): 
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1297759968: 
Exception while property mapping at property path "": 
Property "newfield" was not found in target object of type 
"In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User". | 
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\Exception thrown in file 
\www\typo3_src-8.7.8\typo3\sysext\extbase\Classes\Property\PropertyMapper.php in line 127.
```

It is very strange that the creating (register) is working, but the editing does not!

I think the interessing parts are

```
config.tx_extbase{
    persistence{
        classes{
            In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User {
                subclasses {
                    0 = TOCO3\TocoLedes\Domain\Model\User
                }
            }
            TOCO3\TocoLedes\Domain\Model\User {
                mapping {
                    tableName = fe_users
                    recordType = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    objects {
        In2code\Femanager\Controller\NewController.className = TOCO3\TocoLedes\Controller\NewController
        In2code\Femanager\Controller\EditController.className = TOCO3\TocoLedes\Controller\EditController
    }
}
```

EditController.php

```
namespace TOCO3\TocoLedes\Controller;

class EditController extends \In2code\Femanager\Controller\EditController {

    /**
     * action update
     *
     * @param TOCO3\TocoLedes\Domain\Model\User $user
     * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\ServersideValidator
     * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\PasswordValidator
     * @return void
     */
    public function updateAction(\TOCO3\TocoLedes\Domain\Model\User $user) {
        parent::updateAction($user);
    }
}
```

I'm looking forward any ideas or - this would be great - a working sample extension (Unfortunately femanagerextended ist outdated :-( )

Comment: sorry a typo in EditController: BardehleLedes -> TocoLedes

Answer (score 6):

To help others having the same problem perhaps I have a solution for the PHP 7 warnings too (with help of Steffen Kamper and some hints from here: https://github.com/einpraegsam/femanagerextended/issues/1):

1. Create an XCLASS

   myext/XClass/Extbase/Mvc/Controller/Argument.php

```php
    <?php
    namespace  TOCO3\MyExt\Xclass\Extbase\Mvc\Controller;

    class Argument extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\Argument
    {
        /**
         * Set data type for femanager workaround.
         * Workaround to avoid php7 warnings of wrong type hint.
         *
         * @param $dataType
         * @return $this
         */
        public function setDataType($dataType) {
            $this->dataType = $dataType;
            return $this;
        }
     }
```

2. Register this XClass
   myext/ext_localconf.php

```php
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Controller\\Argument'] = array('className' => 'TOCO3\\MyExt\\Xclass\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Controller\\Argument');
```

3. In NewController.php

```php
    <?php
    namespace TOCO3\MyExt\Controller;
    use TOCO3\MYExt\Domain\Model\User;
    class NewController extends \In2code\Femanager\Controller\NewController {

        /**
         * @return void
         */
        public function initializeCreateAction()
        {
            if ($this->arguments->hasArgument('user')) {
                // Workaround to avoid php7 warnings of wrong type hint.
                /** @var \TOCO3\MyExt\Xclass\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\Argument $user */
                $user = $this->arguments['user'];
                $user->setDataType(\TOCO3\MyExt\Domain\Model\User::class);
            }
        }

        /**
         * action create
         *
         * @param User $user
         * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\ServersideValidator
         * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\PasswordValidator
         * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\CaptchaValidator
         * @return void
         */
        public function createAction(\In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User $user) {
            parent::createAction($user);
        }
    }
```

4. In EditController.php

```php
    <?php
    namespace TOCO3\MyExt\Controller;
    use \TOCO3\MyExt\Domain\Model\User;
    class EditController extends \In2code\Femanager\Controller\EditController {


        /**
         * @return void
         */
        public function initializeUpdateAction()
        {
            if ($this->arguments->hasArgument('user')) {
                // Workaround to avoid php7 warnings of wrong type hint.
                /** @var \TOCO3\MyExt\Xclass\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\Argument $user */
                $user = $this->arguments['user'];
                $user->setDataType(\TOCO3\MyExt\Domain\Model\User::class);
            }
        }

        /**
         * action update
         *
         * @param User $user
         * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\ServersideValidator
         * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\PasswordValidator
         * @validate $user In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\CaptchaValidator
         * @return void
         */
        public function updateAction(\In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User $user) {
            parent::updateAction($user);
       }
     }
```

Comment: 2 things I've noticed: The line after „Create an XCLASS“ isn't actually the path to file. I've copied it blindly until I noticed that the folder name should be „Xclass“ and not „XClass“ and that this folder has to be a subfolder of „Classes“ for the Xclass to work properly.

Comment: This not working for my TYPO3 10.4, femanagaer 6.3.4 and PHP 7.4

Answer (score 2):

Just use the example on github
https://github.com/einpraegsam/femanagerextended

It works perfectly with femananger 3.3.0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the following TypoScript was not included properly via Extension include. If I add it directly as extension template at the profile editing page it works!?

```
config.tx_extbase{
persistence{
    classes{
        In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User {
            subclasses {
                0 = TOCO3\TocoLedes\Domain\Model\User
            }
        }
        TOCO3\TocoLedes\Domain\Model\User {
            mapping {
                tableName = fe_users
                recordType = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
objects {
    In2code\Femanager\Controller\NewController.className = TOCO3\TocoLedes\Controller\NewController
    In2code\Femanager\Controller\EditController.className = TOCO3\TocoLedes\Controller\EditController
}
```

}

I'll have to investigate it some time to find the reason for that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

More Information, see 
[How to extend femanager controller under php 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563671/how-to-extend-femanager-controller-under-php-7/51130418#51130418)

Look also my comments .. I had no problems with the outdated extension `femanagerextended`
https://github.com/einpraegsam/femanagerextended

Good luck.